# What is the running of following code if implement by ArrayList and LinkedList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

```
 for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
        lst.add(lst.size()/2,3*i);          
    }
```

I was thinking that the for loop will take o(n) but I was not clear what what the difference between add(j,t) if using ArrayList and LinkedList..
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inserting in the some slot k of an `ArrayList`, finding k is O(1), but then you're going to have to push back each element after k, which is O(n).  However, inserting at the end of an `ArrayList` is amortized O(1), amortized since we need to factor in the situations when the array needs to be resized.

For a `LinkedList`, unless you have a reference to the element at position k, then you need to iterate through the list to find said position, which is O(n), whereas actually inserting is always O(1).

Comment: @user68498 Since you're new to SO, here take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about).  Besides the good info, I'm shamelessly asking you to accept my answer.

Comment: @SteveP. So, overall it would O(n^2) Since the .add is nested in a for loop?

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell Yes.

Answer (score 1):

For `LinkedList<E>`:

> add(int index, E element) is O(n)

For `ArrayList<E>`:

> add(int index, E element) is O(n - index) amortized, but O(n)
>   worst-case (as above)

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/2498729

Comment: @user68498 If you found this answer helpful/correct, you can upvote it or check mark it. And no problem.  |=^]